# Aborted error message appears when I try to create an entity with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, cmd, entity

I'm trying to create an entity using this ligne command `php bin/console make:entity` but an error message`aborted` appears.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHWnb.png]

So I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes from a bug within the `PHP 7.4` release on windows 10.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34702

How to solve it? Change your PHP version to 7.3

Click to Wamp Icon => PHP => version => select 7.3.12

Also, don't forget to change the PHP version on windows path.

[image]